# Call createForm() and generateUrl() from service in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like have access to controller methods from my custom service. I created class MyManager and I need to call inside it `createForm()` and `generateUrl()` functions. In controller I can use: `$this->createForm(...)` and `$this->generateUrl(...)`, but what with service? It is possible? I really need this methods! What arguments I should use?

Comment: You can pass your controller to your service as parameter, then call $controller->createForm(...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you look to those two methods in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` class, you will see services name and how to use them.

```
public function generateUrl($route, $parameters = array(), $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
{
    return $this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
}

public function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array())
{
    return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options);
}
```

Basically, you class need services `router` and `form.factory` for implementing functionality. I do not recommend passing controller to your class. Controllers are special classes that are used mainly by framework itself. If you plan to use your class as service, just create it.

```
services:
    my_manager:
        class: Something\MyManager
        arguments: [@router, @form.factory]
```

Create a constructor with two arguments for services and implement required methods in your class.

```
class MyManager
{
    private $router;
    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct($router, $formFactory)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    // example method - same as in controller
    public function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->formFactory->create($type, $data, $options);
    }

    // the rest of you class ...
}
```

Comment: And this is the best way to solve this problem! I came to the same before your answer, so we think alike :)

Answer (score -1):

assuming you are injecting the service into your controller , you can pass the controller object to your service function

example

```
class myService
{
  public function doSomthing($controller,$otherArgs)
  {
      $controller->generateForm();
  }
}

class Mycontroller extends Controller
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
      $this->get("my-service")->doSomthing($this,"hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You should just inject the actual service you need rather than inject the controller just to use the `$controller->get()` method. At worst you could inject the `@service_container` and then use that (`$this->container->get()`) but then even that isn't best practice.

Comment: @Qoop so what's your solution ?

Comment: The same as in the accepted answer. Pass in the router and form factory to the service, or as I mentioned use the service container but it's not recommended.